# System reports incorrect disk capacity

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk

I have a 1TB HDD as a storage drive for my computer (running Ubuntu 18.04) that I've used for a few years now. Out of nowhere, the disk is unable to mount properly. `fdisk` currently shows the correct partition sizes for the device,
[but shows the disk size as only 7.9GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP3BZ.png). (While /dev/sdb1 reports as a boot partition, it's worth noting that I don't actually boot to it. It's just an old windows partition I don't really use anymore).

I tried open `gparted`, and got an error saying "Can't have a partition outside the disk!", presumably because it thinks the disk is only 7.9GB in size. I also tried running `lsblk` [but it reads the same size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH6Lc.png).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, turns out it wasn't a software issue at all. The contacts on the SATA connector were a bit dirty. Works fine after cleaning up/plugging back in.